# Main activity exits when requested for permission

Tags: java, android

I have a splash activity as my main activity which requests some permissions or finishes(If some circumstances are satisfied). The problem is when I run app on my `OnePlus` phone with android 9 it works totally fine but when I run it on my `Samsung galaxy s5` with android 6.0.1 (I think is better to be noted that has root access) when I request for permissions right after `requestPermission(...)` is called the activity gets finished and `onPause()` and `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` is called and the dialog for requesting permission is still shown until I allow or deny it.

Even for the test I commented all `finish()` functions but nothing changed.

Here is the code of my activity for more info:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private int CONNECTION_ESTABLISHMENT_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private final String TAG = Splash.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Crashlytics())
                .debuggable(true)           // Enables Crashlytics debugger
                .build();
        Fabric.with(fabric);
        ...

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
        super.onStart();
        if (!((SmartHomeConfiguration) getApplication()).isPermittedForConnectionEstablishment()){
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart: is not permitted to establish connection");
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d(TAG, "onStart: has permissions");
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent myIntent ;
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: changing activity in 1 second");
                        if (userIsSignedUp()) {
                            myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        }
                        else
                            myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, Register.class);
                        Splash.this.startActivity(myIntent);
//                        Splash.this.finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "onStart: does not have permissions");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, CONNECTION_ESTABLISHMENT_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart: is permitted to establish connection");
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent myIntent ;
                    if (userIsSignedUp()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: changing activity in 1 second to home activity");
                        myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    }
                    else{

                        Log.d(TAG, "run: changing activity in 1 second to register activity");
                        myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, Register.class);
                    }
                    Splash.this.startActivity(myIntent);
//                    Splash.this.finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: ");
        if (requestCode == CONNECTION_ESTABLISHMENT_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: granted");
                if (userIsSignedUp()) {
                    ((SmartHomeConfiguration) getApplication()).getConnectionManager().establishConnection();
                }
                else
                {
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent myIntent ;
                            if (userIsSignedUp()) {
                                myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            }
                            else
                                myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, Register.class);
                            Splash.this.startActivity(myIntent);
//                            Splash.this.finish();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                finish();
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: finishing");
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    }


    private boolean userIsSignedUp() {
        return ((SmartHomeConfiguration)getApplication()).getConnectionManager().
                getCurrentHome()!= null &&
                ((SmartHomeConfiguration)getApplication()).getConnectionManager().
                        getCurrentHome().getGatewayProfile() != null;
        }
}
```

***EDIT:***
I have this line in logcat. But I'm not sure if it's the issue:

```
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/myAppID/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.appid.xml.bak
```

Comment: Is your app crashing perhaps? see if you can spot some errors on the log cat and post them here please.

Comment: You probably want to remove all references to hinava code as that is presumably the company you work for? Also, you should strip out all code not pertinent to the question and provide a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo - It doesn't sound like it's crashing, given that it's going through the lifecycle methods...

Comment: I guess issue is because of Fabric. Actually I have also faced this issue and when I commented all code regarding Fabric ,it works fine.In my case Version was 7.0

Comment: @ThomasCook I tried to remove all references to hinava but I forgot these ones.:D Thanks

Comment: @NikosHidalgo No it doesn't crash at all

Comment: @S.Ambika commenting all lines related to fabrics didn't change the result

Comment: is it possible to call request permission method twice. Can you check it ?

Comment: @mrtcnkryln the log before request permission method appeared only once in logcat.